# Query computer name of a remote machine C#

Tags: c#, cmd, windows-server-2012

I have the IP address, username and password of a Windows 2012 R2 Server,
is there any way I can use these details to get the hostname/computer name using C#?

i.e. get the same result as I would get if I opened the cmd of the server and typed hostname:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> hostname
server2012r2
```

Comment: Yeah that's called DNS.

Comment: Use the Dns class : see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143997(v=vs.110).aspx (Though the example doesn't appear to do what it says)

Comment: Thanks very much, I had searched but hadn't found that question! Solves my problem.